# Parsing JSON with Python from URL

Tags: python, json, parsing

So I'm trying to get json from a URl and the request works and I get the json but I'm not able to print specific things from it.

```
    request_url = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/following?limit=1'
    r = requests.get(request_url, auth=oauth).json()


    r["updated"]
```

I'm very new with python I'm guessing I need to get the json into a array but I have no idea where to even begin.

According to the tumblr api I should be able to get something like this.

```
    {
      "meta": {
        "status": 200,
        "msg": "OK"
      },
      "response": {
        "total_blogs": 4965,
        "blogs": [
          {
            "name": "xxxxx",
            "title": "xxxxxx",
            "description": "",
            "url": "http://xxxxxx.tumblr.com/",
            "updated": 1439795949
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I only need the name, url, and updated just no idea how to seperate that out.

Comment: If you are getting the JSON in your example you would need to access `r["response"]["blogs"][0]["updated"]`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, pretty much all of these answers are helpful.  I didn't understand that I had to access the values before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the levels one by one.

```
for i in r["response"]["blogs"]:
    print i["name"],i["url"],i["updated"]
```

So this code can be used to print all the objects inside the `blogs` list

To explain how this works:

Json objects are decoded into something called `dictionaries` in Python. Dictionaries are simple key value pairs. In your example,

r is a dictionary with the following keys:

```
meta, response
```

You access the value of a key using r["meta"].

Now meta itself is a dictionary. The keys associated are:

```
status,msg
```

So, `r["meta"]["status"]` gives the status value returned by the request.

Comment: Is it possible for me to add onto the dictionary with a loop? The tumblr api has a limit of only pulling 20 things at once

Comment: `Add onto the dictionary with a loop`? If u mean adding data to the dictionary, yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to print values as though it were nested arrays:

`r["response"]["blogs"][0]["updated"]` should get you the updated bit, don't go straight to it.  Just work your way down.  Note  how blogs is an array, so in a normal case you may actually want to work towards `r["response"]["blogs"]`, then loop through it and for each of those items, grab the `["updated"]`.

Similarly, `r["meta"]["msg"]` will get you the meta message.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data gets converted as dict which is set to `r` as per your code.

For accessing the value associated with `updated` key, you need to first access the values before it.

You should first access `r["response"]` which contains the actual response of the api. From that level, you should next access `r["response"]["blogs"]` and then loop through that to find the value of the `updated` key.

If it is a single blog, you can do something like `r["response"]["blogs"][0]["updated"]`